# Adding a chart using chart.js. How to call data from a list on different page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest, caml, chart

I am trying to build some visuals in Sharepoint to present the list data in a more useful fashion.

charts.js appears to be a free resource for this purpose so i have been playing with that and have managed to have some working charts.

[This link showed me how to extract data](https://blog.appliedis.com/2014/07/29/transform-your-sharepoint-list-data-into-an-eye-catching-chart/)

The above link used the code

```
function GetChartData() {
seriesarray = [];
var currentcontext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var splist = currentcontext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Fruit Consumption');
var splistquery = new SP.CamlQuery();
splistitems = splist.getItems(splistquery);
currentcontext.load(splistitems)
```

Which worked fine when on the page containing the list. allitems.aspx
However when I use that same code to add into a webpart on a new page it doesn't call the list data.

I guess something needs to be changed in

```
var splist = currentcontext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Fruit Consumption');
```

due to the data being on a different page.

Would anyone know what I need to change to make it work?

Many thanks

Comment: Use a REST query instead. You would need to change the function to parse the json response but that should be relatively straight forward.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response. I have no idea how to do that yet! I will google it and try and learn now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SPServices](http://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/) or [SharePointPlus](https://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/) but I suggest you to use [SharePointPlus](https://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/) to get data from list. You can use SQL like syntax and it is really easy to use.

> SharepointPlus ($SP) is a JavaScript library which offers some
>   extended features for SharePoint entirely on client side (requires no
>   server install). $SP will simplify your interactions with the
>   Sharepoint Web Services and will help you to deal with the List Forms.

[image]